# Center multiple labels with multiple textarea

Tags: html, css

I have multiple labels and textareas together. They line up like in this:

```
       __________________
      |                  |
      |                  |
Label:|__________________|
```

And I want it to be like:

```
       __________________
      |                  |
Label:|                  |
      |__________________|
```

There has been answers for this problem **Except for that I have multiple labels and textareas together.** So I tried to use the answer:

**CSS:**

```
.label_textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class="label_textarea">
<label>Label for textarea</label>
<textarea rows="5">Textarea</textarea>
</p>
```

but this doesn't work for me. It's not changing anything in the layout.
Also the amount of combinations of labels and textarea is different everytime so I cant use a standard amount.

What should I do here to get the result I want?

Comment: Hi, as you can see in the accepted answer on the question you linked, the `vertical-align` property is set on the children (`label ` and `textarea`) with `.formfield *` selector and not on the container as you did in your example.

Comment: @web-tiki Aha yes thank you but I still needed to do some changes that weren't in that answer to get it working though.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/s6pzo2hx/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `line-height` property for label along with `vertical-align` **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cLqn9pys/)**

CSS:

```
label {
    line-height:50px;
    vertical-align::middle;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
textarea {  
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label>label</label>
    <textarea></textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: Just for the label, or for the textarea as well?

Comment: just for label, not for textarea